# Consecutive calls to 'SOAPMessage.writeTo' throw Read Error

Tags: java, soap, saaj

SOAP message in my application contains an attachment created from a file.
When I give a call to ***soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);*** for more than single time, it throws following exception :

```
SEVERE: SAAJ0540: Error during saving a multipart message
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Error during saving a multipart message
    at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.writeTo(MessageImpl.java:1233)
    at main.SOAPMTOMUtilityTest.main(SOAPMTOMUtilityTest.java:102)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Read error
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
```

Is this a bug ? Or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: I found out the cause. It was the 'MyDataSource' class which was returning the same inputStream. It is expected to return a new InputStream everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the cause. It was 'MyDataSource' class which was returning the same inputStream. It is expected to return a new InputStream everytime it gets a call.

```
public class MyDataSource implements DataSource {
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {

        //return inputStream;
InputStream inputStream= new FileInputStream(file);
return inputStream;
    }
}
```